# Internal Service Errors on PayPal RestAPI Sandbox STILL creates an authorization

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Until recently I have had no problems with the PayPal REST API Sandbox. I am sending an authorization. It fails. BUT the authorization is still created!

Here is the JSON that I send:

```
{"intent":"authorize","payer":{"payment_method":"credit_card","funding_instruments":[{"credit_card":{"number":"4111111111111111","type":"visa","expire_month":1,"expire_year":2016,"cvv2":"123","billing_address":{"line1":"1234 Bobby Lane","city":"Lawton","country_code":"US","postal_code":"73170","state":"OK"}}}]},"transactions":[{"amount":{"currency":"USD","total":"286.35","details":{"shipping":"0","subtotal":"286.35","tax":"0"}},"description":"This is the payment transaction description."}]}
```

Here is the response:

```
{"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"21a877318e6e6"}
```